# Reference request for QFT $SO(3)$ non-linear sigma model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, resource-recommendations, non-linear-systems, sigma-models

I was wondering if anyone has a reference that could help me understand quantum field theories that have a nonlinear configuration space. For example, from classical mechanics if we have a three-dimensional rigid body with a rotational configuration space of $SO(3)$, then the corresponding Euler-Lagrange equations are put in terms of Euler angles (for reference, Goldstein chapters 4 and 5). Specifically, if I had a theory of three scalars, $\mathbf{\phi} = (\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3)$ in four-dimensions with a Lagrangian density of,
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}  =-\frac{M^2}{4}\text{Tr}(\partial_\mu U\partial^\mu U^\dagger),
\end{equation}
where $U = \exp(i\mathbf{\sigma}\cdot\mathbf{\phi})$ and with $-i$ for $U^\dagger$, then what would the dynamics or amplitude look like? I know I could expand the exponentials out to some order in $\phi$, throw it into the functional correlation function to find propagators, vertices up to different order, and what not, but when it comes to understanding what is really going on, that's where I am lost and would just like a reference, or even someone or some paper that has worked this out since I figure there are also other parameterizations, just as in classical mechanics, with using $SU(2)$ instead. I don't think Srednicki's text has anything on this, but I will keep looking as well.

EDIT: after @Qmechanic made an edit to this post (thank you) the tag of sigma-model was added which helped me understand what I am looking at: a $SO(3)$ non-linear sigma model and the $2\rightarrow 2$ scattering amplitude for such a model.

Comment: For SU(2) and SO(3) all group elements *U* can be written down explicitly and operated upon, so if you are expanding exponentials you are doing something off... The textbooks by M Schwarz, H Georgi, and Itzykson & Zuber beat the matter to death...

Comment: You've mastered [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_model), no?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Well, to be completely honest, no. In class we haven't even mentioned sigma models. (This is for a hw where I want a reference/starting point but $\textbf{not}$ an answer. I really want to understand this). We didn't touch chiral models last semester, and have done bound states with Bethe-Salpeter amplitude (thank you Itzykson and Zuber), analytic properties of the amplitude, and now IR divergences. And it looks lie Itzykson has a section on chiral models, a paragraph on nonlinear ones, and that is it. I will check out Schwarz's textbooks.

Comment: @CosmasZachos This actually seems like a starting place: [non-linear sigma model from a theory of SU(2) marix](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87434/derive-non-linear-sigma-model-from-a-theory-of-su2-matirx).

Comment: Yes, but the full expansion sums [to this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector), only for SU(2). Schwartz's book pp 401-3 gets to the point...